# Sequence and Series bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Let $ x_n $ be a sequence defined by $x_n = \displaystyle {\sum_{k=n+1}^{ 2n}\frac{1}{k}}$. Show that $ x_n$ converge.

I can bounded $ x_n <\frac{ n}{ n+1}$, but I can't show that $ x_n$ is increasing, thus would use that es increasing and bounded then is convergent.

Comment: Did you try squeezing $x_n$ between two integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k &=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k -\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{k}\\\\
&\to \log(2)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^{2n}\frac1k =\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+k/n}$$

which is a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1):

Simply notice that, since $\frac{1}{2n+1} > \frac{1}{2n+2}$, $$x_{n+1} - x_n = \sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{2n+1}  + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{2}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} = 0.$$
Hence the sequence is increasing. Then apply your bound $x_n \le \frac{n}{n+1} < 1$ to conclude convergence.

Comment: Necessarily the expression $ x_n > 0 $?

Comment: I have shown $x_{n+1} - x_n > 0$, which proves $x_{n+1} > x_n$, i.e. the sequence is increasing. It's also true that $x_n > 0$, since it's a sum of positive numbers.

Comment: Thanks,  now I can continue.